# Using RMI over different network

Tags: java, rmi

The guest's computer can be on a network other than the server's.
If it isn't, everything is OK, but when he is, a `ConnectException` is thrown.

Do you know why ?

***Extra info:***
I modified the port from 1099 (default) to 80 to try to solve the problem, doesn't work.
Using Wireshark, I saw that guest were using port 50740. I don't understand why, and never saw this number before.
I grant all permissions with a .policy file.

***Edit :***
I already have server IP defined by a .bat. I also have `Locate.createRegistry(80);` at the beginning of my client. Is it enough to make client use port 80 ?

Strange thing is that i can try to log in (my app asks for a login when launched), see if my credentials are OK or not. Then, if client isn't on the same network, the `ConnectException` is thrown.

Comment: This is not a java/rmi question imo.

Comment: I think it's not possible, Ive had this problem and in  in my case I had to use sockets instead of RMI. Theres a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268391/java-rmi-over-the-internet

Comment: @Andreas Oh yes it is.

Comment: @fanm Oh yes it is. You did your rewrite for nothing. The link you cited is about *callbacks.*

Comment: I already have server IP defined by a .bat. I also have Locate.createRegistry(80); at the beginning of my client. Is it enough to make client use port 80 ?

Strange thing is that i can try to log in (my app asks for a login when launched), see if my credentials are OK or not. Then, if client isn't on the same network, the ConnectException is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

> I modified the port from 1099 (default) to 80 to try to solve the problem, doesn't work. Using Wireshark, I saw that guest were using port 50740. I don't understand why, and never saw this number before.

When an RMI client wants to talk to a remote object it typically starts by contacting the RMI registry on port 1099 to ask where it can find the target object.  The registry replies with a stub containing the address of the target object (host name and port number), and the client can then connect to the target host and port to talk to the remote object.

If you don't specify an explicit port number in the call to the `UnicastRemoteObject` superclass constructor or the static `exportObject` method, then RMI will select a random available port number to use.  That's probably where the 50740 comes from - it's the port that the target object is listening on, as opposed to the registry.

But the second element of the target object address is the host name - if the object is listed in the registry at an address like `127.0.0.1:50740` then a client on a different machine will end up trying to connect to the object in the wrong place (on the *client's* localhost rather than the server's).  The solution is to ensure that the objects are bound in the registry under a proper host name or IP address that is resolvable from the client - in theory this should happen automatically, but sometimes RMI gets it wrong.  The solution is to pass a system property to the RMI server (the process that is binding the target object in the registry)

```
java -classpath .... -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.1 com.example.MyRmiServer
```

Replace `192.168.0.1` with the correct IP address that the client machine will use to talk to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your remote objects on a fixed port number, and open that port in your firewall. The easiest port to use is 1099 as it's already reserved, but it requires that you start the Registry in your JVM via `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` instead of using `rmiregistry`, so you can share the port.